# Merge dbf files from different folders in Python or Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, dbf, append

I am new to Python. I have over one hundred dbf files to merge in two diffrent workspaces.

Workspace 1:
PCPT100100
PCPT101101
PCPT102101

Workspace 2:
s100100
PCPT101101
s102101

I want to merge "PCPT100100 (workspace1) - s100100(workspace 2)", "PCPT101101 -PCPT101101".....
I am using the tool "append" but I don't know, how can I specify the name of the files.

I read about `glob` or `os.walk` to find files recursively.

Example:

```
import arcpy,glob


# Local variables:
PCPT100111_dbf = "C:\\PCPT100111.dbf"
s100110_dbf__2_ = PCPT100111_dbf

yourlist = glob.glob(r"C:\\s*.dbf)

s100110_dbf = "C:\\s100111.dbf"

# Set Geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\"

# Process: Append
arcpy.Append_management("'C:\\PCPT100111.dbf'", s100110_dbf, "NO_TEST", "Field1 \"Field1\" true false false 10 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\PCPT100111.dbf,PRECIPITAT,-1,-1", "")


print "Append is done"
```

Comment: The merge tool https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000 works on tables, you need to supply a list of input names if the tables are in the current workspace and full paths if the tables are not. As for walking I would suggest arcpy.da.Walk https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000023000000 with datatype='Table' to find all the tables from a given folder and all subfolders.. does this sound like what you're after? I wouldn't put your DBF in the root of C drive and try walking, if you don't have a D then move to a subfolder on C.